# "Шапка" в виде таблицы для другой таблицы

Tags: html

Подскажите пожалуйста как с помощью таблиц (применение bgcolor только к `<table>`) используя inline-css(без подключений css и js и без `div` и `display:block`), сделать адаптивную "шапку" для таблицы "`<!-- Table wraper -->`" ?. Код на [облаке](http://codepen.io/discipleartem/pen/XbJeab). Пробовал разные варианты, не получилось.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table bgcolor='#dfdfdf' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td height='10px'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align='center'>Text</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td height='30px'></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody align='center'>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!-- Table wraper -->
            <table bgcolor='#f2f2f2' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#f2f2f2'>
              <tr>
                <td width='20px'></td>
                <td>
                  <!-- Table body -->
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table border='0'>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              Значение:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              @очень_длинная_переменная
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <tr>
                        <td height='10px'></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table border='0'>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                Значение:
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                @длинная_переменная
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                          <td height='10px'></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <table border='0'>
                              <tr align='left'>
                                <td>
                                  @переменная
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  x
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  @переменная
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  @переменная
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                          <tr>
                            <td height='5px'></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tr>
                      </tr>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
                <td width='10px'></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Как "шапка" черного цвета (без размытия) на изображении [image: так]

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, скриншот, демонстрирующий желаемое поведение.

Comment: уже добавил ...

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqPXzw - это?

Comment: нет, нужно черную, адаптивную по ширине "шапку"(для таблицы <!-- Table wraper -->), как на картинке. При чем фон (bgcolor) должен применяться только к тегу table

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bmusn0pk/

Comment: да, именно так, спасибо. Скопируйте код в ответ и я приму (хотя бы с 11-21 строки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @soledar10

```html
    <table bgcolor='#dfdfdf' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
      <thead>
        <tr><td height='10px'></td></tr>
        <tr><td align='center'>Text</td></tr>
        <tr><td height='30px'></td></tr>
      </thead>
        
      <tbody align='center'>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!-- Table wraper -->
            <table bgcolor='#f2f2f2' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#f2f2f2'>
               <tr>
                   <td colspan="3">
                        <table bgcolor='#000' style="color:#fff;" width="100%">
                            <tr><td>header</td></tr>
                       </table>
                   </td>
              </tr>
                       
              <tr>
                <td width='20px'></td>
                <td>
                  <!-- Table body -->
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table border='0'>
                          <tr>
                            <td>
                              Значение:
                            </td>
                            <td>
                              @очень_длинная_переменная
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                      <tr>
                        <td height='10px'></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                          <table border='0'>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                Значение:
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                @длинная_переменная
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                          <td height='10px'></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>
                            <table border='0'>
                              <tr align='left'>
                                <td>
                                  @переменная
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  x
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  @переменная
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                  @переменная
                                </td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                          </td>
                          <tr>
                            <td height='5px'></td>
                          </tr>
                        </tr>
                      </tr>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
                <td width='10px'></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```